# Python why can't range from larger to smaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, sum, range

I'm trying to write a python program that can receive inputs and sum all numbers from the range it creates, and it works normally as it should when user inserts 10 and 20, for example. I need to make it work when the user inputs 20 and 10 (big to small), but the program always returns 0. I have not found this specific question anywhere on the internet.

Comment: Post your code please

Comment: Please, put a piece of you code so it would be possible to reproduce the problems you are facing. This guide should help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have destroyed my code because it displeased me and ruined my day. I cannot get a range(20,10) to return anything other than 0, doesn't matter the operation.

Comment: @MarkKush: `range(anything)` doesn't return `0`. Your script may return `0` because that's the exit success code (and it presumably raised no exceptions). `range(20, 10)` produces nothing because it's an empty sequence; the duplicate explains how to make it actually descend.